# My master is getting update with PR when I am not even raising PR against it

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have three main branches. `master` , `dev` and `rel`. We are taking pull from `dev`, make new feature-branch from it, then raise PR against `dev`. After some days, I went to `master` branch from github  and saw all PRs which I have raised against `dev`, were already merged into `master`. We were never expecting that thing to happen. `master` was never included on any process. I went again to see how commits came into `master` and it was from PR which was to the base branch `dev`.

Is it the case that the parent branch gets automatically merged if the PR is merged onto its child branch or something like that.

Really need help on this and how this behaviour can be prevented.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to enable branch protection. On GitHub Enterprise, navigate to the main page of the repository.

Under your repository name, click  Settings.

In the left menu, click Branches.

Under Protected Branches, select the branch you want to mark protected using the drop-down menu.

Select Protect this branch.

Click Save changes.

[image]

For detailed information check out this [link](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/admin/developer-workflow/configuring-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks).

Comment: My question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Point 9 from the shared link states applying status checks can let you control the way you merge into master.

Comment: Its not that someone is pushing. Its something else I am asking @Sunny

Comment: Normal workflow doesn't allow Github to merge into master unless you define a Github action to do so automatically. Perhaps, you can check the git logs to see if it was accidentally merged by any member of your team. My solution was only, to ensure that even if someone accidentally tries to merge anything to master, the status check would but only block it from happening. Kudos @AbhirajTulsyan! :)

Comment: I have checked that please. I am saying they are the same commit. When I say how that commit came into master, it redirect to that PR only.

Comment: It's certainly weird @AbhirajTulsyan. The usual workflow should be 

git checkout master

Then making sub branch for dev as in 

git checkout -b dev

When you need to make further changes to develop, cut new branches in a similar fashion while develop is checked out:

git checkout -b feature

To merge a feature back into your develop branch, checkout develop and execute a merge:

git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff feature

Comment: @AbhirajTulsyan I could look into your problem & if you want we can take it further with chat discussion.